# passing values from one jInternalFrame to another jInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jinternalframe

can anyone help how to pass value from one jInternalFrame1 to another jInternalFrame2?I can't make object of the jInternalFrame1 in jInternalFrame2.I have seen one solution by making constructor and oject the Jframe.But how?

Comment: 1)You can pass it through the constructor, or 2) have setters and getters, or 3) Use a data Model that is shared between the two.

Comment: can you provide code for this data Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "can you provide code for this data Model?"

The second internal frame accepts a `DataModel` object. The two will remain the same object when between the frames.

Note if you need something more complex (like back and forth interaction between the frames), you should look into some tutorial on [**Model View Controller architecture**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html), where you will need to use `PropertyChaneListeners` and such

```
public class DataModel {
    private String data;

    public DataModel() {
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }    
}

public class MyInternalFrame1 extends JInternalFrame {
    private DataModel dataModel = new DataModel();

    public DataModel getDataModel() {
        return dataModel;
    }

}

public class MyInternalFrame2 extends JInternalFrame {
    private DataModel dataModel;

    public MyInternaFrame1() {}

    public MyIntenalFrame2(DataModel datModel) {
        this.dataModel = dataModel;
    }

    public void setDataModel(DataModel dataModel) {
        this.dataModel = dataModel;
    }
}
```

In the Main GUI program, you can do something like this

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {
    MyInternalFrame1 iFrame1 = new MyInternalFrame1();

    ....
    // somewhere else in code
    DataModel dataModel = iFrame1.getDataModel();
    dataModel.setData("Hello");
    new MyInternalFrame2(dataModel);
}
```